# Are you able to use a custom Postgres comparison function for ORDER BY clauses?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

In Python, I can write a sort comparison function which returns an item in the set `{-1, 0, 1}` and pass it to a sort function like so:

```
sorted(["some","data","with","a","nonconventional","sort"], custom_function)
```

This code will sort the sequence according to the collation order I define in the function.

Can I do the equivalent in Postgres?

e.g.

```
SELECT widget FROM items ORDER BY custom_function(widget)
```

**Edit:** Examples and/or pointers to documentation are welcome.

Comment: @bendem: It's possible, though not straightforward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205878/order-by-using-clause-in-postgresql

Comment: This is more a question for [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: using Nico's clues [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63792480/287948), with other explanations.

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can, you can even create an functional index to speed up the sorting.

Edit: Simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    id serial primary key,
    bar int
);
-- create some data
INSERT INTO foo(bar) SELECT i FROM generate_series(50,70) i;
-- show the result
SELECT * FROM foo;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_sort(int) RETURNS int 
LANGUAGE sql 
AS
$$
    SELECT $1 % 5; -- get the modulo (remainder)
$$;
-- lets sort!
SELECT *, my_sort(bar) FROM foo ORDER BY my_sort(bar) ASC;

-- make an index as well:
CREATE INDEX idx_my_sort ON foo ((my_sort(bar)));
```

The manual is full of examples how to use your own functions, just start playing with it.

- SQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html
- PL/pgSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html

Comment: I thought so, sorry for the rather "obvious" question but...how on earth do I do this?  The documentation and Google don't seem to provide me with obvious answer.  A few more details/examples would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Check the simple example. Now it's up to you and your imagination :-)

Comment: Thanks for the extra example.  Your function only takes one variable, though.  In Python the sort function takes two variables.  If variable 1 should go before variable 2, it returns -1.  If they're equal, 0, and if var 2 should go before var 1, it returns 1.  I still don't see the equivalent here.

Comment: As I said, it's up to your imagination, PostgreSQL doesn't have (many) limitations. If you want a function with 2 parameters, just make one. If you need 10 parameters, just go for it. Start using pl/pgsql and make an if-else construction for your comparison.

Comment: Frank Heikens, it seems to me, that You are missing the point. Sean Woods said, that the function in Python takes in two elements and compares them. In PostgreSQL, it would translate to taking in two rows and comparing them, and returning which is bigger. You are correct that You can create a function to use for sorting, that takes in two arguments, but it seems to me, that these two arguments would be from the SAME row, not two different rows.

Comment: Rauni is correct, and @FrankHeikens's solution does not exactly answer the question. To put what Rauni said another way, the function in this answer is not a comparator function, it is a function that transforms the value into something that gives the desired order when sorted with the built in comparators.

Comment: This index didn't work by the way, using explain analyze shows that it used a quicksort, not an index scan.

Comment: @thouliha: There is never a guarantee that an index will be used. Sometimes using an index is actually slower than a sequential scan. It depends on the data and the statistics.

Comment: I'm trying to get *any* functional index to be used under any circumstances, and I can't. All my function indexes are being ignored.

Comment: Ah nevermind, after I inserted several thousand series, it used your index. My bad. Can function indexes have more than one input? I'm trying to do a simple ranking based on a score and a published time. I have the function, and it allows me to ceate the index, but it always gets ignored.

Answer (score 5):

We can avoid confusion about [ordering methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) using names:

- *"score function"* of standard SQL `select * from t order by f(x)` clauses, and
- *"compare function"*  ("sort function" in the question text) of  the Python's sort array method.

---

The `ORDER BY` clause of PostgreSQL have **3 mechanisms** to sort:

1. Standard, using an "score function", that you can use also with INDEX.
2. Special  "standard string-comparison alternatives", **by [collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html) configuration** 
   (only for `text`, `varchar`, etc. datatypes).
3. `ORDER BY ... USING` clause. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7461843/287948) or [docs example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xindex.html#XINDEX-EXAMPLE). 
   Example: `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY somecol USING ~<~` where `~<~` is an operator, that is embedding  a *compare function*.

Perhaps "standard way" in a [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#RDBMS) (as PostgreSQL) is not like Python's standard because indexing is the aim of a RDBMS, and it's easier to index score functions.

Answers to the question:

- Direct solution. **There are no direct way** to use an user-defined function as *compare function*, like in the *sort method* of languages like Python or Javascript.
- **Indirect solution**. You can use a *user-defined compare function* in an *user-defined operator*, and an  *user-defined operator class* to index it. See at PostgreSQL docs:

  - [CREATE OPERATOR](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html) with the *compare function*;
  - [CREATE OPERATOR CLASS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createopclass.html), to be indexable.

---

#### Explaining *compare functions*

In Python, the *compare function* looks like this:

```py
def compare(a, b):
    return 1 if a > b else 0 if a == b else -1
```

**The *compare function* use less CPU tham a *score function***. 
It is usefull also to express order **when *score funcion* is unknown**.

See a complete description at

- for C language see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Comparison-Functions.html
- for Javascript see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

#### Other typical compare functions

[Wikipedia's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Performance_limits_and_advantages_of_different_sorting_techniques) to compare tuples:

```
function tupleCompare((lefta, leftb, leftc), (righta, rightb, rightc))
    if lefta ≠ righta
        return compare(lefta, righta)
    else if leftb ≠ rightb
        return compare(leftb, rightb)
    else
        return compare(leftc, rightc)
```

In Javascript:

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

C++ example of [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xindex.html#XINDEX-EXAMPLE):

```c
complex_abs_cmp_internal(Complex *a, Complex *b)
{
    double      amag = Mag(a),
                bmag = Mag(b);

    if (amag < bmag)
        return -1;
    if (amag > bmag)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (interval_alias) *,
  to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' FROM index.created_at) / 10)) * 10) AT
  TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS interval_alias
  FROM index
  WHERE index.created_at >= '{start_date}'
  AND index.created_at <= '{end_date}'
  AND product = '{product_id}'
  GROUP BY id, interval_alias
ORDER BY interval_alias;
```

Firstly you define the parameter that will be your ordering column with `AS`. It could be *function* or any *SQL expression*. Then set it to `ORDER BY` expression and you're done!

In my opinion, this is the smoothest way to do such an ordering.