# "ORDER BY ... USING" clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

The ORDER BY clause is decribed in the PostgreSQLdocumentation as:

```
ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC | USING operator ] [ NULLS { FIRST | LAST } ] [, ...]
```

Can someone give me some examples how to use the `USING operator`? Is it possible to get an alternating order of the resultset?

Comment: What do you mean by "alternating order"?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A very simple example would be:

```
> SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY col USING <
```

But this is boring, because this is nothing you can't get with the traditional `ORDER BY col ASC`.

Also the standard catalog doesn't mention anything exciting about strange comparison functions/operators. You can get a list of them:

```
    > SELECT amoplefttype::regtype, amoprighttype::regtype, amopopr::regoper 
      FROM pg_am JOIN pg_amop ON pg_am.oid = pg_amop.amopmethod 
      WHERE amname = 'btree' AND amopstrategy IN (1,5);
```

You will notice, that there are mostly `<` and `>` functions for primitive types like `integer`, `date` etc and some more for arrays and vectors and so on. None of these operators will help you to get a custom ordering.

In *most* cases where custom ordering is required you can get away using something like `... ORDER BY somefunc(tablecolumn) ...` where `somefunc` maps the values appropriately. Because that works with every database this is also the most common way. For simple things you can even write an expression instead of a custom function.

*Switching gears up*

`ORDER BY ... USING` makes sense in several cases:

- The ordering is so uncommon, that the `somefunc` trick doesn't work.
- You work with a non-primitive type (like `point`, `circle` or imaginary numbers)  and you don't want to repeat yourself in your queries with strange calculations.
- The dataset you want to sort is so large, that support by an index is desired or even required.

I will focus on the complex datatypes: often there is more than one way to sort them in a reasonable way. A good example is `point`: You can "order" them by the distance to (0,0), or by *x* first, then by *y* or just by *y* or anything else you want.

Of course, PostgreSQL *has* predefined operators for `point`:

```
    > CREATE TABLE p ( p point );
    > SELECT p <-> point(0,0) FROM p;
```

But *none* of them is declared usable for `ORDER BY` by default (see above):

```
    > SELECT * FROM p ORDER BY p;
    ERROR:  could not identify an ordering operator for type point
    TIP:  Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.
```

Simple operators for `point` are the "below" and "above" operators `<^` and `>^`. They compare simply the `y` part of the point. But:

```
    >  SELECT * FROM p ORDER BY p USING >^;
    ERROR: operator > is not a valid ordering operator
    TIP: Ordering operators must be "<" or ">" members of __btree__ operator families.
```

`ORDER BY USING` requires an operator with defined semantics: Obviously it must be a binary operator, it must accept the same type as arguments and it must return boolean. I think it must also be transitive (if a < b and b < c then a < c). There may be more requirements. But all these requirements are also necessary for proper **btree**-index ordering. This explains the strange error messages containing the reference to **btree**.

`ORDER BY USING` also requires not just *one operator* to be defined but an *operator class* and an *operator family*. While one *could* implement sorting with only one operator, PostgreSQL tries to sort efficiently and minimize comparisons. Therefore, several operators are used even when you specify only one - the others must adhere to certain mathematical constraints - I've already mentioned transitivity, but there are more.

*Switching Gears up*

Let's define something suitable: An operator for points which compares only the `y` part.

The first step is to create a custom operator family which can be used by the **btree** index access method. [see](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/xindex.html)

```
    > CREATE OPERATOR FAMILY xyzfam USING btree;   -- superuser access required!
    CREATE OPERATOR FAMILY
```

Next we must provide a comparator function which returns -1, 0, +1 when comparing two points. This function *WILL* be called internally!

```
    > CREATE FUNCTION xyz_v_cmp(p1 point, p2 point) RETURNS int 
      AS $$BEGIN RETURN btfloat8cmp(p1[1],p2[1]); END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    CREATE FUNCTION
```

Next we define the operator class for the family. [See the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/xindex.html) for an explanation of the numbers.

```
    > CREATE OPERATOR CLASS xyz_ops FOR TYPE point USING btree FAMILY xyzfam AS 
        OPERATOR 1 <^ ,
        OPERATOR 3 ?- ,
        OPERATOR 5 >^ ,
        FUNCTION 1 xyz_v_cmp(point, point) ;
    CREATE OPERATOR CLASS
```

This step combines several operators and functions and also defines their relationship and meaning.  For example `OPERATOR 1` means: This is the operator for `less-than` tests.

Now the operators `<^` and `>^` can be used in `ORDER BY USING`:

```
> INSERT INTO p SELECT point(floor(random()*100), floor(random()*100)) FROM generate_series(1, 5);
INSERT 0 5
> SELECT * FROM p ORDER BY p USING >^;
    p    
---------
 (17,8)
 (74,57)
 (59,65)
 (0,87)
 (58,91)
```

Voila - sorted by *y*.

**To sum it up:** `ORDER BY ... USING` is an interesting look under the hood of PostgreSQL. But nothing you will require anytime soon unless you work in *very* specific areas of database technology.

Another example can be found [in the Postgres docs.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xindex.html#XINDEX-EXAMPLE) with source code for the example [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/tutorial/complex.source) and [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/tutorial/complex.c). This example also shows how to create the operators.

Comment: I am debating implementing an operator class and a comparator function to do sorting of model versions ("1.4.0" < "1.4.0.1" < "1.21.0"). Is there an easier way that you would suggest?

Comment: This is what i have been looking for the past 2 days. With this functionality, one can compare jsonb cells holding different types of values. It removes the need for dynamic SQL statements of such situations.

Answer (score 4):

Samples:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "number" integer,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

insert into test("number") values (1),(2),(3),(0),(-1);

select * from test order by number USING > //gives 3=>2=>1=>0=>-1

select * from test order by number USING < //gives -1=>0=>1=>2=>3
```

So, it is equivalent to `desc` and `asc`. But you may use your own operator, that's the essential feature of `USING`

Comment: Can you give me an example using a custom operator?

Comment: I'm curious about that, too. That sounds like a quite nifty feature of Postgres, there

Comment: Well, the simple `Create function op_func ...` => `Create operator === (procedure = op_func` => `order by ===` throwed me `ERROR:  operator === is not a valid ordering operator
LINE 1: select * from test order by number USING ===
                                                 ^
HINT:  Ordering operators must be "<" or ">" members of btree operator families.`. I'm not quite familiar with operator classes and families, so can't come up with example yet. I'll investigate it, but I'm no PostgreSQL guru actually...

Comment: Well, it's not easy to find something on google. This looks like a rather internal feature...

Answer (score 3):

Nice answers, but they didn't mentioned one real valuable case for ´USING´.

When you have created an index with non default operators family, for example  `varchar_pattern_ops` ( `~>~`, `~<~`, `~>=~`, ... ) instead of `<`, `>`, `>=` then if you search based on index and you want to use index in order by clause you need to specify `USING` with the appropriate operator.

This can be illustrated with such example:

```
CREATE INDEX index_words_word ON words(word text_pattern_ops);
```

Lets compare this two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'o%' LIMIT 10;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'o%' ORDER BY word LIMIT 10;
```

The difference between their executions is nearly 100 times in a 500K words DB! And also results may not be correct within non-C locale.

How this could happend?

When you making search with `LIKE` and `ORDER BY` clause, you actually make this call:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word ~>=~ 'o' AND word ~<~'p' ORDER BY word USING < LIMIT 10;
```

Your index created with `~<~` operator in mind, so PG cannot use given index in a given `ORDER BY` clause. To get things done right query must be rewritten to this form:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word ~>=~ 'o' AND word ~<~'p' ORDER BY word USING ~<~ LIMIT 10;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'o%' ORDER BY word USING ~<~ LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Optionally one can add the key word ASC (ascending) or DESC
>   (descending) after any expression in the ORDER BY clause. If not
>   specified, ASC is assumed by default. Alternatively, a specific
>   ordering operator name can be specified in the USING clause. An
>   ordering operator must be a less-than or greater-than member of some
>   B-tree operator family. ASC is usually equivalent to USING < and DESC
>   is usually equivalent to USING >.

[PostgreSQL 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY)

It may look something like this I think (I don't have postgres to verify this right now, but will verify later)

```
SELECT Name FROM Person
ORDER BY NameId USING >
```

Comment: The line you left out is interesting too: `(But the creator of a user-defined data type can define exactly what the default sort ordering is, and it might correspond to operators with other names.)`

Comment: I think the OP already knows this; they are asking for usage examples

Comment: I already read that, but can you give other examples than "using <" and "using >"?

Comment: `select * from test order by number USING > 1` not working in PostgreSQL 9.0. But `select * from test order by number USING >` works. So it should be an operator, not comparison.