# PostgreSQL Error: operator >> is not a valid ordering operator

Tags: postgresql, operators, b-tree

First off I am not too experienced with postgresql so I apologize in advanced. I recently upgraded my server from postgresql version 8.3 to version 9 and after restoring my data I ran into a problem with operators in one of my queries which I cannot solve. I am trying to query:

> database=# select bbox from dems order by bbox using >> limit 1;

bbox is a column in my table dems of type box.

I get result:

> Error: operator >> is not a valid ordering operator
>
> Line 1: select bbox from dems order by bbox using >> limit 1;
>
> HINT: Ordering operators must be "<" or ">" memeber of btree operator families.

I thought that the ">>" operator was built into postgresql for type box and am wondering what I am doing wrong here. The query worked perfectly with version 8.3. My old coworker wrote the original code and set up the server so I might be missing a few restoration steps. Any help would be great, I will continue reading through documentation in the mean time.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `>>` is an ordering operator, since it is highly possible for none of `a << b`, `a >> b`, or `a = b` to be true.

Comment: I wrote about `ORDER BY .. USING ...` [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7461843/947357). Perhaps it helps you to understand where to look for the missing parts in the old system.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem here is that you appear to be trying to generate a tree of contained boxes by simply ordering them.  Ordering is not the way to do this.  Instead use a with recursive query and a window function (both require 8.4 or higher iirc).  In this case, something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE bbox_tree (id, bbox, level, position, path) AS
( select id, bbox, 1, rownumber() over (order by id), id::text
   from dems
  UNION ALL
 SELECT d.id, d.bbox, t.level + 1, rownumber over (partition by t.id order by d.id),
        p.path || ',' d.id
   FROM dems d
   JOIN bbox_tree t ON t.bbox >> d.bbox )
SELECT bbox FROM  bbox_tree order by string_to_array(t.path, ',');
```

You are actually going to have to create a tree here.