# Implement custom comparison in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plv8

I have some data in a postgres table with one column called version (of type varchar). I would like to use my own comparison function to to order/sort on that column, but I am not sure what is the most appropriate answer:

- I have an JS implementation of the style comp(left, right) -> -1/0/1, but I don't know how I can use it in a sql order by clause (through plv8)
- I could write a C extension, but I am not particularly excited about this (mostly for maintenance reason, as writing the comparison in C would not be too difficult in itself)
- others ?

The type of comparisons I am interested are similar to version string ordering used in package managers.

Comment: How about a custom operator? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html

Comment: I looked at that link but could not figure out whether I needed my own type to attach custom operators, or whether I could 'override' it on a per-column basis ?

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
ORDER BY mycolumn USING operator
```

See [the docs for `SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY). It looks like you may need to define an operator for the function, and a b-tree operator class containing the operator to use it; you can't just write `USING myfunc()`.

(No time to test this and write a demo right now).

Comment: This is correct, and the operator can be implemented with a function defined using whatever, include plpgsql. Another answer here goes into more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205878/order-by-using-clause-in-postgresql